# flutter Bring nested collection from firestore

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on flutter app I have created collection called 'publicPost' and inside that have the documents and then I have another nested collection with its documents as shown at the image.

the problem is when I tried to retrieve and show all data from the 'publicPost' I can't. I need to specify one doc and it will bring the data of the one doc only. how can i bring all document from the main collection.

this is my code of saving the data

```
 sendData() async {
    final _documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("publicPosts")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    final _collectionReference = _documentReference.collection("postlist");
    Map<String, dynamic> userInfoMap = {
      "address": _addressController.text,
      "bloodType": neVal,
      "place": _placeController.text,
      "post": _postController.text,
      "date": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      "username": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email,
      "name": '$firstNmae $lastName',
    };
    await _collectionReference.add(userInfoMap);
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

and thats how i tried to retrive using this code  but i dose't work

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('publicPosts')
      .doc()
      .collection('postlist')
      .snapshots();
```

Can anyone help please to solve this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To load documents from all `postlist` collections, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collectionGroup('postlist')
      .snapshots();
```